# C# Saving Object List Vs Saving Object (From JSON)

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I have the following WORKING code:

Class (declared objects)

```
public class saveRow
{
    public int proId { get; set; }
    public string proName{get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult SaveRow(saveRow input)
{ /* CODE HERE */}
```

JavaScript Object (Been sent)

```
var test = {"proId" : 1, "proName" : "Test"}
```

JavaScript Ajax Call

```
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "URL",
       dataType: "json",
       data: test,
       traditional: true,
       success: function (data, status, request) {
           if (data.Error != undefined) {
               alert("System Error: " + data.Error);
               $(row).find('*').attr('disabled', false);
               return;
           }

       },
       error: function (request, status, error) {
           console.log("ERROR");
       }
   });
```

Now the problem occurs when I want to send a list of my rows rather than one at a time so i done the following:

To test i took the same object and done

```
var test2 = []; test2.push(test); test2.push(test);
```

And the object now looks like:

```
[{"proId" : 1, "proName" : "Test"},{"proId" : 1, "proName" : "Test"}]
```

My controller now looks like :

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual JsonResult SaveRow(List<saveRow> input)
{ /* CODE HERE */}
```

Also tried `IEnumerable` when sending the list of objects as JSON the variable input is always null.

But every time I send this list through the controller parameter "input" is always null.

Why is this?

SOLVED:

```
public virtual JsonResult SaveRow(saveRow[] input)
```

And added content type! With `JSON.stringify`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

- Set a wrapper name for your list same as that of your argument name "input"
- Set content-type
- Remove traditional and use JSON.stringify to stringify your data.

JS:

```
var data = { "input": test2 };

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "URL",
       dataType: "json",
       contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8", //<--Set content Type
       data: JSON.stringify(data), //Set data
       success: function (data, status, request) {
           if (data.Error != undefined) {
               alert("System Error: " + data.Error);
               $(row).find('*').attr('disabled', false);
               return;
           }

       },
       error: function (request, status, error) {
           console.log("ERROR");
       }
   });
```

Comment: Ahhh i see what you getting at here, currently added it and project is builidng will update outcome.

Comment: @LmC Yeah let me know how it goes.. If it doesn't work just paste what you see in the network console for the request part.

Comment: Hi still the same issue my object looks like {"input" :[ {},{}]} please note {} is just short for the sturcture shown above to keep comment tidy

Comment: Cache is disabled (using chorme dev tools)

Comment: I would love to know why, its a mystery!